# correct type of statistical correlation test for aggregated dataset

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I was wondering if you can suggest a statistical test that can be applied to this sort of dataset. I am staying away from machine learning techniques as the dataset is small, and due to the aggregated data values might not benefit for ML techniques

I have users, list of stores a users visits and number of items he buys from that store, and total number of returns for that user. The problem would be much easier if I knew which items the user return to which stores but unfortunately I don't have that information, I only know the total number of items returned by the user. This is what the data looks like.

| userID | items bought at store A | items bought at store B | items bought at store C | total items returned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UserA | 10 | 5 | 3 | 6 |
| UserB | 15 | 4 | 4 | 8 |

I understand that this is not the best / most accurate data, and there might not be a suitable test, but can we infer something about the stores, and the total items returned by the user in a case like this? If we assume a return rate per store, like 20%, can we say that for user A 2 items were returned for store A, 1 for store B, and so on?

Thank you

Comment: Are there any distributional assumptions you are willing to make about these observations?

Comment: I am not sure, but the distribution of my data is right skewed bimodal, it looks like the image here (slide 6)
http://media.news.health.ufl.edu/misc/bolt/Intro/PHC6050-6052/Unit1/0105-Transcript-Describing-Distributions.pdf

Thank you